# Create a polygon clip path css and background in nativescript

Tags: nativescript

Need to create a same that:

[image]

The polygon (creates with clip path css) and background. Need polygon with a circle on four corners.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As given in the [docs](https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/styling), you could use [clippy](https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/) to calculate `clip-path` and use it in your CSS.

```
.clip {
 clip-path: polygon(24% 29%, 63% 7%, 83% 79%, 33% 71%);
}
```

Comment: i know this, but how can create bullet on corners?

Comment: You would know the points / path for the polygon, you may have to just use a absolute layout that can hold circles at those positions.

Comment: I have created perfectly my absolute clip-path. Now have a problem for positions of 4 points (Label) on respective 4 corners. How can do it? In AbsoluteLayout right and bottom not exist. have a good idea?